# Issue with tcl regex to extract beginning portion of the string

Tags: regex, tcl

I am trying to extract the beginning portion of the string until the last '.' as follows. In the example below I need to get $sig as abcd.q. Please help.

```
% set a abcd.q.alpha
abcd.q.bist
% regexp "^(.*)\..*$" $a match sig
1
% puts $sig
abcd.q.bis
```

Comment: Your value is in capture group 1.

Comment: I get abcd.q.bis, but I need abcd.q

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your expression is that `^(.*)\..*$` is not doing what you probably want it to do. More specifically, `\.` is really just being converted to a simple `.` and thus the reason why you are getting all but the last character. In Tcl, it's better for you to use braces for regular expressions like so:

```
regexp {^(.*)\..*$} $a match sig
```

And that should give you the result you are looking for.

---

One simple way you can check whether your regular expression is good or not is to assign it to a string:

```
% set re "^(.*)\..*$"
^(.*)..*$
```

Not exactly what we want... but this:

```
% set re {^(.*)\..*$}
^(.*)\..*$
```

Is what we are looking for. Quotes in Tcl allow substitution, while braces don't.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I figured the solution:

```
regexp "(.*)\[\.\].*$" $a match
```